# Using angular as the platform for workshop management

Tags: angular

I am conducting a system for my course, to manage a workshop online, where the customer will also be able to keep track of what is happening with his vehicle. this would have to be with a web service because it would have to be creating an application and a website.

my idea and create the site using the angular, and a webservice using laravel.

I am including the angular in my project because I want to learn it, my doubts are:

in the context of the context in which I reported a management system:

- What is the difference between angularjs and angular (What do you
  create by cmd)?
- Can the angular exchange information with the web service via ajax?
  in the same way as jquery?
- Would it be more beneficial to use jquery?
- Is it easy to put an online site angular?
- Is angular safe?

Comment: This doesn't meet stack overflows guidelines for asking a good question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between angularjs and angular (What do you
>   create by cmd)?

Angular is faster, uses typescript which is easier to read and "ore" strictly typed, it has a better documented command line interface that lets you generate any type of code structure you could need.

> Can the angular exchange information with the web service via ajax? in
>   the same way as jquery?

Of course it can. It uses the HttpClient. Network requests are network request.

> Would it be more beneficial to use jquery?

You can use both? But angular has easier to read documentation, so why not stick with that?

> Is it easy to put an online site angular?
>     As easy as any other publishing method, if not easier, because packaging is taken care of by the CLI.
>
> Is the angle safe?

If by angle, you mean angular, then yes. There are a ton of sanitizations put in place to keep things from displaying in a harmful way in addition to plenty of tools to keep routing and data flow under control.